# html2canvas callback Onrendered doesn't work in Angular 2

Tags: angular, html2canvas

In Angular 2 project, I have installed the html2canvas module with version number 0.5.0beta.

Then in my TS file, I have import it as:

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

Then in my pdfDownload method, that I have written,

```
html2canvas (document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
                        onrendered : function (canvas) {
```

After this, when I execute the `npm start` command, I got error like,

> onrendered is not a property defined in html2canvasOptions.

Can anybody help me resolving this issue?
This is the first time I am working on angular 2 and html2canvas.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 14):

Probaby you use html2canvas 0.5 version. [onrendered](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/v0.4/readme.md#usage) was used in 0.4 and older versions. html2canvas 0.5 was rewriten to use [Promises](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas#usage).
You have to change

`html2canvas (document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
                 onrendered : function (canvas) {`

to

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis')).then(function (canvas) {
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem.

I was able to solve it by declaring the option object outside `html2canvas` function call. Something like. This prevent the TS compiler from checking for the passed option object for internals.

```
var obj = {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  }
};
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("exportthis"), obj);
```

**EDIT**:
After upgrade of typescript to 2.4.0 , if you get below error

```
TS2559: Type '{ onrendered: (canvas: any) => void; }' has no properties in common with type 'Html2CanvasOptions'.
```

then add any of Html2CanvasOptions property like logging: false

```
obj = {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  },
  logging: false
};
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("exportthis"), obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newImg;
saveImage() {
html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture')).then((canvas) => {
  this.newImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
})
}
```

`<img [src]="newImg" alt="">`

FOR INSTALLATION:

`npm install @types/html2canvas --save`